# Marklogic Logging Customizations

Tags: marklogic

I am exploring logging in MLv8 and discovered we can set certain log levels and rotation on log files through the ML's admin console. But coudn't find answers to some of the customization's which were required for us:

- Can we rename or change location of the Error log file which is by default:
  Windows: C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data\Logs\ErrorLog.txt,
  Linux: /var/opt/MarkLogic/Logs/ErrorLog.txt
- Can we customize the content of log file (like date format)
- Is it possible to have multiple log files as per log level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no facilities to customize the default file logger that’s built into MarkLogic. However, in addition to the `ErrorLog.txt` you can also send log messages to the system logger (syslog on *NIX). From there, you can use all of the downstream logging tools designed for system logs. There’s a [section in the docs](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/logfiles#id_29580) that covers configuration of the system logger. (I even built a [proof-of-conept](https://github.com/jmakeig/marklogic-syslog-server) that will save syslog messages as JSON to a MarkLogic database.)

Comment: Thanks Justin..The link 'section in the docs' above takes me to 'Viewing the System Log' section in the MarkLogic documentation.. Is that correct !

Comment: Yes, that's correct. There’s not much to document from the MarkLogic end.  The magic happens in the system log. One thing to call out is that you can set different log level for files and system logs. For example, you could log errors and above in `ErrorLog.txt` while still sending more granular debug or notices to syslog.